# run two or more queries on one button click

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I want to insert data in two different table on button click. So there are 2 insert queries with different credentials. The first insert query working properly but second is not executing. Here what I tried.

```
Try
            Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO yogaClasses (`yogaID`,`name`, `category`, `websiteName`, `email`, `phone1`, `phone2`, `mobileNumber`, `buildingName`, `streetName`, `landmark`, `areaName`, `city`, `State`, `zipCode`, `address`, slotTime1From, `slotTime1To`, `slotTime2From`, `slotTime2To`, fees, `overview`, `establishment`, `newBatchStart`, `yogaType`, `facilities`, payment, `status`, `username`, `password`) values ('" + ID + "','" + name + "', '" + businessCategory + "', '" + website + "', '" + email + "', '" + phoneNo1 + "', '" + phoneNo2 + "', '" + mobileNumber + "', '" + building + "', '" + street + "', '" + landpoint + "', '" + area + "', '" + city + "', '" + stateName + "', '" + zipCode + "', '" + fulladdress + "', '" + slot1A + "', '" + slot1B + "', '" + slot2A + "', '" + slot2B + "', '" + feesPay + "', '" + about + "', '" + foundYear + "', '" + startnewBatch + "', '" + selectedYoga + "', '" + selectedFacility + "', '" + payments + "', 'active', '" + mobileNumber + "', '" + membersAutoPassword.Text + "')"

            Dim str2 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            command.CommandText = str1
            command.Connection = con
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            con.Open()
            str2 = command.ExecuteReader
            con.Close()
            Response.Redirect("business-added.aspx")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try



Try
            Dim str2 As String = "INSERT INTO yogaAgeGroup (`6-15`, `16-20`, `21-25`, `26-30`, `31-35`, `35+`, `yogaID`) values('" + ageup1.Text + "', '" + ageup2.Text + "', '" + ageup3.Text + "', '" + ageup4.Text + "', '" + ageup5.Text + "', '" + ageup6.Text + "', '" + TextId.Text + "')"
            Dim str3 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            command.CommandText = str2
            command.Connection = con
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            con.Open()
            str3 = command.ExecuteReader
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
```

The second query not executing. What I am doing wrong in this? Or Is it possible to execute both query in one?

Comment: Don't use `ExecuteReader` with an INSERT statement.  You should use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem (in your 1st query)

```
con.Close()
Response.Redirect("business-added.aspx")
```

Move this line after second query con.Close()

```
Response.Redirect("business-added.aspx")
```

Because this line will redirect you to another page, so the rest of code won't be execute